# Why the JDK Timer for Spring is not working?

Tags: spring, timer, java

Im writting a Spring Application, which has to run a task in a new thread that should be started every couple of seconds. My XML looks like this:

```
<bean id="checkEmail" class="com.turbineam.dataloader.commons.QuartzSchedulerBean"></bean>

<bean id="scheduledTask" class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.ScheduledTimerTask">
    <property name="delay" value="1000" />
    <property name="period" value="1000" />
    <property name="timerTask" ref="checkEmail" />
</bean>
```

And for Java code I have:

```
package com.turbineam.dataloader.commons;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class QuartzSchedulerBean extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("printMe!");
    }
}
```

But it doesn't affect my whole program (which makes something else)

how can I make this right?

Kind Regards,

Rafał

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a TaskExecutor implementation.

See: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-executor

Comment: Thanks. I managed to do this without executor. I actually added TimerFactoryBean, and it didnt work. Then, I added lazy-init = "false" to all 3 beans and now its working.

So now i have something like this: <bean id="checkEmail" class="com.turbineam.dataloader.commons.QuartzSchedulerBean" lazy-init = "false></bean>. And the same trick to scheduledTask bean and TimerFactoryBean.